# Hint only, please. Solving $e^{2x}\le e^x+6$ and $\sin\left(4x\right)<\cos\left(4x\right)$

Tags: inequality

No solution, please. Just hint what I should do to get to a simplification.

$$e^{2x}\le e^x+6$$

$$\sin\left(4x\right)<\cos\left(4x\right)$$

Comment: You should include something about what you know of solving such problems, and where you are stuck. This will help answerers avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) telling you things you already know; also, it can help them avoid giving you too much of a hint and spoiling your fun.

Comment: Are these a system of inequalities that you are trying to combine, or separate? If they are together use complex exponential representations of sines and cosines.

Comment: @Durabys You need to mention `simultaneous solution' and need to put `and' between the two inequations.

Comment: They are separate inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first: Consider it a quadratic inequality in $y=e^x$.

The second: Shift one of the arguments so that both are sines or cosines and then apply an appropriate trigonometric formula.

Comment: Thanks, man! This what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

$z=e^x$

The first one becomes a quadratic

In second one divide by cos (4x) which becomes$tan(4x)<0$ but here cos(4x) >0

Find the intersection of this inequality
Then take case when cos(4x)<0 then $tan(4x)>0$ find intersection of this also.Then u'll get the inequality

Comment: The second hint is half wrong, you do not compare to zero afterwards. What about $\cos 4x<0$?

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

For the first,
observe that
$$e^{2x}-e^x-6=(e^x+2)(e^x-3)$$

and that $$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \;\; e^x+2>0$$

For the second.
Put $z=4x$.
Then, the inequation can be written as

$$\sin(z)-\cos(z)<0$$

or

$$\sqrt{2}\Bigl(\frac{\sin(z)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\cos(z)}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr)<0$$

which is equivalent to

$$\sin(z-\frac{\pi}{4})<0$$

thus

$$z-\frac{\pi}{4} \in \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb Z}(-\pi+2k\pi,0+2k\pi)$$
and

$$4x\in \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb Z}(-\frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi)$$

You can finish.

Answer (score -1):

The domain for $$f(x)=e^{2x}-e^x-6<0 \implies (e^x-3)(e^2+2)<0$$ is $x <\ln 3.$
$f(-\infty)=-6, f'(x)=e^{x}(2e^x-1)=0 \implies x=-\ln 2, f''(-\ln 2) = 1/2>0, f_{min} =-\frac{25}{4}$.  So for $x<-\ln 2$, the range of $f(x)$ is $R_1: (-25/4,-6)$.

Next, the function $g(x)=\sin(4x) -\cos(4x)$ is periodic and bounded in $R_2 :[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}],$ as $R_1 \cap R_2=\phi$ (null), so there will be no real root. See below corves $f(x)$ (red) anf $g(x)$ (blue) they do not intersect for $x<0$, or more precisely for $x<\ln 3$.

[image]